# The $n^{th}$ derivative of $y = x^{a}$ where $a$ is a positive fraction?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It obviously works the same way as if $a$ was just an integer which would suggest I'd write it as follows $y^{(n)} = (a - n + 1)! \cdot x^{a-n}$ but I can't do that because $a$ is not an integer.

I don't really have any idea where to go with this. The only idea I have had was to use that notation that's similar to $\sum$ except it's for multiplication (an uppercase Pi) but we haven't studied that notation, ever, so I thought there must be some other way I can answer this question otherwise it wouldn't have been included in our problem sets.

Comment: I suspect you are expected to write $a(a-1)\cdot (a-n+1)$ as the coefficient. (By the way, your original formula is incorrect. I think you intended a quotient of factorials.)

Answer (score 1):

There exist so called Gamma function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function
$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. It can be extended to complex plane (excluding negative integers), so your idea has a sense (with some definition of, say, $a!$ instead of your $(a-n+1)!$).

Comment: We haven't studied that either. I believe my solution needs to be within the scope of what I have studied. This is my first college year and we are taking Calculus this semester.

Comment: @EyadH. So you can simply define the coefficient by induction, similarly as factorial is defined.